# Could we harness the energy from room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

If no atom is at absolute zero, it must have kinetic energy. Therefore, could we harness that energy, (sure for small objects, not much energy would come of it) but surely the earth itself has a ton of energy accumulated from the many vibrating atoms. If it is possible, how much matter would we need to make this efficient?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Do you want to do work and use a heat pump with room temperature heat, in order to heat something up?  Or do you want to use a heat engine to extract room temperature heat to do work?

Comment: Please describe the process you have devised for extracting the heat from the room air or from the earth and using it to do work.

Comment: Creating energy from heat would violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics, because it would decrease entropy. A device that could harness energy from heat would be a type of [Maxwell's Demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To harness thermal energy, you need a temperature gradient between the source and the sink.
To give you an analogy, suppose that we want to do work using water. For that we need water at different levels, i.e there should be a potential difference so that water can flow and do work as in hydroelectric power plants. 
In your case, you would need a sufficient temperature difference between the source (the room) and the sink. Since the temperature difference between the different parts of the room is very small,the amount of useful work would be negligible.
The efficiency of a heat engine is given by

$\eta = 1 - \frac{T_{sink}}{T_{source}}$

where $T_{source}$ is the temperature of the source and $T_{sink}$ is the temperature of the sink. In your case both of these would be appromimately equal and hence efficiency would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

No. To harness energy to create work, the energy needs to flow. In other words, the work come from energy changes; differences in energy, when leveled, can cause a change in the world: work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, extracting this energy is the basis of a heat engine. It can be done as long as you have a heat reservoir at a lower temperature. The efficiency will always be less than or equal to the efficiency of a Carnot engine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how a heat pump works.  You can even take in cold air, compress it and it gets hot, extract the heat, expel the air, take in new air, repeat.  If you compare the energy used to compress the gas with the heat obtained you actually get more heat than if you had just burned the energy.

Answer (score 0):

That is what [geothermal heat pumps do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_heat_pump) in the winter:

> A geothermal heat pump or ground source heat pump (GSHP) is a central heating and/or cooling system that transfers heat to or from the ground.
>
> It uses the earth all the time, without any intermittency, as a heat source (in the winter) or a heat sink (in the summer). This design takes advantage of the moderate temperatures in the ground to boost efficiency and reduce the operational costs of heating and cooling systems, and may be combined with solar heating to form a geosolar system with even greater efficiency.

So the answer is yes, the thermal energy stored in the ground is exploited  for improving energy efficiency in heating in the winter. This means it delivers more watts in heat  than the watts  spent in its elecric circuits

The same is true for airconditioner inverters, which take energy from the air, cooling it in the winter in order to increase the energy for heating a house.